# Would you call a person who has a personality similar to Lincoln a Lincoln or a Lincolner?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Would you call a person who has a personality similar to Lincoln a Lincoln or a Lincolner?

Also, does Lincolner have any political connotations, like someone supporting the Republican party?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a metaphor, "a Lincoln."  Looking for an adjective?  Then, "Lincolnesque."  "Lincolner," while I can (barely) see the logic, is not found as such in a Google search.

Comment: When you say you can barely see the logic do you mean the logic of seeing Lincolner as a noun or tying that to someone supporting the Republican party?

Comment: Lincoln sounds better then Lincolner to me for some reason but Lincolner makes it unambiguous that it is distinct from the name 'Lincoln'. I'm not a native Enlgish speaker, would you find 'Lincolner' a good coice for a noun meaning a person with a similar character to Lincoln?

Comment: I understand my reluctance to use Lincolner. -er is used frequently for an inhabitant of a place. E.g. an inhabitant of the city Lincoln. Unfortunately there is already a city called [Lincoln](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lincoln,_Nebraska) so I can't use Lincolner.

Comment: I think "a Lincoln" is correct because I know "a Judas" is also used in the English language, coming from the name of the person Judas.

Answer (score 2):

"Lincolner" would be ambiguous as it brings to mind Lincoln in the UK http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lincoln,_England

Comment: Actually no, certainly not with most people. Besides, what is wrong with ambiguous? Pretty much every single word on this page is ambiguous.

Comment: That depends on who in particular you mean by *most people*. As a British person, the question certainly made me think of Lincoln in the UK.

Comment: It would logically mean *one who Lincolns*; is that something to do with the breed of sheep?